# Does using an immediate return on a function inside useEffect() alter behavior in any way?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Will the following pieces of code behave differently:

A:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    doSomething();
  }, []);
```

B:

```
  useEffect(() => doSomething(), []);
```

Or will they behave the same?

Comment: [`useEffect` expects a cleanup function as a return value](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#cleaning-up-an-effect), if it ever happens accidentally, it could lead to surprises!

Comment: Yes, can pass a function reference in directly to useEffect, but you will probably want to make sure it's bound to the correct scope either through a closure or .bind (and make sure never to pass in async functions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what `doSomething` returns. If it returns undefined, there is no difference. If doSomething returns a function, then that function will be used as the teardown logic for the effect.

If it returns something else, i *think* it gets ignored by react, but you'll want to be sure. As i primarily develop in typescript, i never return anything other than undefined or a function, since it's a type error to return anything else.

Answer (score 1):

So When you return a function from `useEffect`, it says that the said function will run before that `useEffect` runs again. So basically, you return a cleanup function from `useEffect`.

consider this scenario

```
useEffect(()=>{

  const timer = setTimeout(()=>{
     setResult(result+1)
  },3000)
  return ()=>{
     clearTimeout(timer)
  }

},[result])
```

The above code essentially says that when the timeout is executed, your result state will be incremented by one, and when next time the same function is executed, your previous timer variable is cleared up.

Also, if you pass an empty array to `useEffect` and you return clean up function, it act same as `componentWillUnmount` method.

Answer (score -2):

What could possibly be the benefit to returning a function inside useEffect? From what I discern, there isn't a good reason to add this complexity.